# Drools limitations?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am exploring drools for my project I would like to know from more experienced people out there if there are any limitations on the type of rules we can create in drl, can we make an api call in a rule in drools? is it possible to pass extra data along with the pojo I want to apply rules on?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for this site: it's much too broad and better suited for a discussion forum. But basically you can write rules against any data that you pass in. If you have "streaming" data, you can even write rules based on other temporal events (eg. "did i receive a heartbeat within the past 30 seconds?" or "did this event occur while this other event was occurring?")

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.